# Permission denied to go to home directory

Tags: file-permissions

I recently copied a file as the root user to my users's home directory. Ever since that my user has not been able to go to its home directory because "permission is denied". I have already chowned the directory so that it is owned by the user but still i'm getting the error.

(OS: Debian Lenny)

Can canyone help?

RayQuang

Comment: Please post the permissions of your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the directory is also **readable** by the user. So, for a home directory the octal permissions should typically be 700 or rwx------